# get select option text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list that contains the following values:

```
<select id="selectOption">
<option value="10">within 10 miles</option>
<option value="25">within 25 miles</option>
<option value="50">within 50 miles</option>
<option value="100">within 100 miles</option>
<option value="250">within 250 miles</option>
<option value="500">within 500 miles</option>
```

I'm using jquery to obtain the select option text when a selection has been made and then assign the select option value to a variable:

```
    alert($j("select option:selected").text());
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 10 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 25 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 50 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 100 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 250 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }
    if($j("select option:selected").text() == 'within 500 miles'){
        distance = $j("select option:selected").val()
    }

    alert(distance);
```

The insane thing is this works in my development org, but when I push it out to my staging area it no longer works.  I'm getting the following value spit back out to me when I display the alert:

"SearchAllwithin 100 miles"

It should just be:
"within 100 miles"

Where is the additional "Search All" text coming from?????  I can't find where that is coming from??

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `if` statements when you're doing the same thing with every one? And your alert should only be returning a number based on this code.

Comment: Can you show more of your HTML?  My guess is that "Search All" is used somewhere else in the page and is somehow getting added in, but it's hard to tell how/where without seeing the code.

Comment: And you probably have another select element on the page where the selected option is "Search all"

Comment: Since this `if` logic is still startling me, I made a fiddle with a significantly less amount of code, does it do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kUsBx/

Comment: @adeneo - my thought exactly . . . a very wide selector like `"select option:selected"` would do exactly that . . .   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly get the selected index value by using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#selectOption').change(function()
   {
      var dis = $('#selectOption').val();  
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have other `select` on your page use `id` for selector.

There is no need for `if conditions`. Try this:

```
alert($('#selectOption option:selected').text());
distance = $('#selectOption option:selected').val();
alert(distance);
```

Comment: `$('#selectOption').text()` Wrong. This will return the **entire option's text**.

Comment: @user1671639 Thanks for pointing out I have updated the answer with `$('#selectOption option:selected').text()`

Comment: Thanks all!  I appreciate the help.  Using the change event handler did work.  One question, I had to place the change function insider the document ready function at the top of the page.  If I place the change event handler inside my separate javascript function where I originally had the if statements, it doesn't fire.  I'm new to jquery, so can anyone explain why?

Comment: Make sure `jQuery` reference added before that file / function then it will work.

Comment: The `jQuery` reference is added before the function and the change function doesn't fire within my `getAccountsNearbyMap()` function.  I have to place it at the top of the page inside the `$j(document).ready(function() {`.  This is okay, but I have to make the distance variable global instead of just having the variable inside my `getAccountsNearbyMap()` function.

Comment: You can use `$j(document).ready(function() {` in your `getAccountsNearbyMap()` funciton, to make `distance` it `global` variable declare it outside function like `var distance = 0;` or `window.distance = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting *select all* attached with all options.  Maybe by mistake you may have that text in it.

Since you're **`jQuery`**,  go for `.change` event handler.

I think you don't even need `if..else..` statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selectOption').on('change', function() {
  //---- Todos
  $(this).find('option:selected').text(); //get the selected option's text
  var distance = $(this).find('option:selected').val();  //get the selected option's value     
  // or even $(this).val();
  alert(distance);
  });
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ySkqe/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the selected value then just use

```
var distance = $j("#selectOption").val()
```

and no need to select the text and then value.